# ERROR in ./node_modules/@floating-ui/dom/dist/floating-ui.dom.esm.js

Tags: npm-install, react-select

trying to retrofit react-select to provide more functionality in select (especially when there are a large number of options).

The code is pretty vanilla (have suppressed a lot for brevity)

```
import Select from 'react-select';

    export default class ForensicFlowViewer extends React.Component {

    ...

    render()

    ...

    const filterlist = filterList = [{value:'-1', label: 'Select Filter'},
                { value:'autonomoussystem', label: 'AS'},
                { value:'appid', label: 'Application'},
                { value:'dstsubnet', label: 'Dest Subnet'}];

    ...


    <Select className='form-control input-sm'
                                                    id='filterName'
                                                    name='filterName'
                                                    value={this.state.filterName}
                                                    onChange={this.handleFilterChange}
                                                    options={filterList}
                                                    />
    ...
    }
```

When doing an npm install, the compiler issues the following message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@floating-ui/dom/dist/floating-ui.dom.esm.js
[INFO] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (391:6)
[INFO] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
[INFO] |   } else {
[INFO] |     const mutableRect = {
[INFO] |       ...clippingAncestor
[INFO] |     };
[INFO] |     if (isClientRectVisualViewportBased()) {
[INFO]  @ ./node_modules/react-select/dist/react-select.esm.js 24:0-26
```

Package JSON has:

```
"dependencies": {
      "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
      "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
      "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
      "@floating-ui/react": "^0.23.0",
      "axios": "0.21.1",
      "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
      "codemirror": "5.47.0",
      "concurrently": "^5.0.0",
      "css-loader": "0.28.4",
      "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
      "eslint": "5.4.0",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.2",
      "griddle-react": "1.13.1",
      "gulp": "^4.0.2",
      "gulp-autoprefixer": "6.0.0",
      "gulp-clean-css": "4.0.0",
      "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
      "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
      "gulp-less": "3.0.3",
      "gulp-rename": "1.4.0",
      "gulp-sourcemaps": "2.6.4",
      "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
      "highcharts": "^7.1.2",
      "highcharts-react-official": "^2.2.2",
      "is-json": "2.0.1",
      "lodash.debounce": "4.0.8",
      "lodash.uniqby": "4.7.0",
      "mdbreact": "4.15.0",
      "mixin-deep": "2.0.0",
      "moment": "2.22.1",
      "papaparse": "4.6.1",
      "prop-types": "15.7.2",
      "react": "16.14.0",
      "react-addons-shallow-compare": "15.6.3",
      "react-bootstrap-modal": "4.2.0",
      "react-codemirror2": "6.0.0",
      "react-datetime": "2.14.0",
      "react-dom": "16.14.0",
      "react-router-dom": "5.0.0",
      "react-select": "^5.7.2",
    "react-sparklines": "1.7.0",
    "react-step-range-slider": "1.4.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "sockjs-client": "1.3.0",
    "standard": "11.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "ua-parser-js": "^0.7.20",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.2.5",
    "webpack": "3.12.0"
   },
   "overrides": {
    "react-step-range-slider": "1.4.1",
    "griddle-react": "1.13.1"
   },
   "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "ie >= 8",
    "edge >= 15",
    "ie_mob >= 10",
    "ff >= 45",
    "chrome >= 45",
    "safari >= 7",
    "opera >= 23",
    "ios >= 7",
    "android >= 4",
    "bb >= 10"
   ],
    "babel": {
     "presets": [
       "@babel/preset-env",
       "@babel/preset-react"
     ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
     ]
   }
```

Can anyone assist on where things might be going awray?

Have upgrade npm (16.14), node (8.11), babel (7) & gulp (4), and have had to exclude some dependencies until we upgrade.